# Which MongoDB engine is best suitable when using sharding?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB with sharding. Which MongoDB engine is more suitable for this use case in terms or performance and stability - WiredTiger or MMAP? Particularly, is there any impact on ACID properties for different engines?

Comment: Not sure how sharding would effect your choice of engine. And no, there is no real difference with MongoDBs lack of ACID properties between the two. The only real difference is in memory, disk, compression and locking management

Comment: It's a very broad question, and it basically depends on what your application is doing. WiredTiger is probably going to be better at concurrent writes than MMAP, and MMAP is probably going to be better than WiredTiger for lots of reads on a consistent working set. Some reading up would help. Better yet, test it.